# Is it possible to check if two BufferedImage are the same even if one of them is rotated?

Tags: eclipse, maven, bufferedimage

I would like to check in eclipse if two BufferedImages are the same or not. I am using the following method:

```
boolean bufferedImagesEqual(BufferedImage img1, BufferedImage img2) {
        if (img1.getWidth() == img2.getWidth() && img1.getHeight() == img2.getHeight()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < img1.getWidth(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < img1.getHeight(); y++) {
                    if (img1.getRGB(x, y) != img2.getRGB(x, y))
                        return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It returns true if the image is not rotated. What I want to check is that if the two images has the same content (even if they are rotated in different positions). I have the idea to rotate them four times (always with 90°) and if one time they are the same the method returns true. But I don't think that it is the cleverest way to do it. Any idea?

Comment: If you are testing using `getRGB(x, y)`, wouldn't just swapping x/y count as a 90° rotation? You can also use width-x and height-y for 180°. Combine the two for the 270° case. However, I think a dedicated library, like OpenCV might be a better fit for this task.

Comment: Oh someone from KIT, funny.